# Появление на рынке Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile-development

Всем привет! Вопрос такой: стоит ли опасаться того, что разработка с помощью Flutter вытеснит в скором времени ios и android направления по отдельности (иными словами, стоит ли кидаться сейчас изучать Dart и осваивать Flutter) ?

Comment: не стоит опасаться. flutter займет свою нишу не более. основная разработка будет нативная

Answer (score 5):

Любая кросплатформенная разработка имеет достаточно узкую сферу применения. Многие нативные функции, такие как шифрование, работа с аппартной частью и другие подобные, практически невозможно нормально реализовать в кроссплатформенной части.

Пока очень мало приложений, особенно объёмных, можно легко реализовать(перевести) на каком либо кроссплатформенном фреймворке. Всегда будет часть функционала которую надо реализовывать нативно.

Сфера кроссплатформенных фреймворков - создание прототипов для проверки гипотез или быстрого выхода на рынок. После, в случае успеха, почти всегда всё переписывают в нативный код.

Так что не переживайте, нативная разработка всегда будет в приоритете.

Comment: `такие как шифрование, работа с аппартной частью и другие подобные, практически невозможно нормально реализовать в кроссплатформенной части.` относиться только к JavaScript (RN, Cordova/Ionic), Python (Kivy) и Xamarin, такие как Flutter, QT, спокойно это делают (притом они являются нативно-компилируемыми, т.е. AOT)...

Comment: @MiT , не знаю, как там в кордове и киви, но xamarin прекрасно справляется с нативной частью, и тоже может компилироваться в AOT